# Apparent depth and the viewing angle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, refraction

Does the viewing angle of a person observing a coin placed in a bucket of water affect the apparent depth in any way?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is obvious.

Comment: How is it obvious?

Comment: @Artemisia One thing you might want to try is drawing a very careful diagram showing light leaving an object under water at different angles. You'd need a protractor & such to get the angles just right. Trace back your rays and see if you're able to say either way.

Comment: That helped provide the intuition to support the derivation given below :) Thank you

Comment: Related and useful : [How does apparent depth depend on viewing angle?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/440043/238167)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Apparent depth of the object is given by the following equation,
$$AD=\frac{RD}{n_{ab}}$$
Where $AD$ is apparent depth, $RD$ is real depth, and $n_{ab}$ is the refractive index of medium b (denser medium) w.r.t medium a (rarer medium).

As real depth and refractive index is going to be constant always (for the given pair of medium), apparent depth will be independent of viewing angle.

Comment: The equation you give is only true when you're looking directly downwards, not at an angle, so I'm afraid you've drawn the wrong conclusion.

Comment: @JohnRennie. Thank you for the comment. Even when we look at an angle, refracted ray and incident ray will be such that refractive index will remain constant. So, I think apparent depth is not going to vary. If anything wrong here, I will be happy to know.

Comment: When viewing at an angle, the image will be shifted both vertically and horizontally. I remember doing a problem in Irodov about it.