# Apparent depth is supposed to be independent of viewing angle but this seems inconsistent with critical angle refraction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, refraction

When rays from the object at some depth are draw so as to be incident at the critical angle (or some angle just lower) the ray is refracted along the surface. Retracing this line would give you an image directly above but on the surface of water. How then can one state that apparent depth doesn't depend on viewing angle?

Comment: Who ever said that apparent depth is independent of viewing angle?

Comment: @DanielSank ,well it is supposed to be according to another question on this site (http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/99393/apparent-depth-and-the-viewing-angle?rq=1 ) and in many other places on the net.

Comment: That question has one answer that was accepted with zero upvotes, and a comment on there by John R. to the effect that the answer is incomplete. Well, John's right.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably talking about an object under water, watched from outside (air). Given the object's and observer's position, you have to then find an angle for the light originating from the object, refracted on the surface, to hit the observer. As the observer is above the surface of the water, the angle of the light in the water can only be below the critical angle. Of course there is other light hitting the surface with the critical angle and above, but this light does not play a role here.

As the light path is reversible, you can also start from the observer, searching for an angle to hit the object in the end (which is basically what happens, the observer searches for the angle under which he sees the object). Now you are passing from the lighter medium to denser, and you find that there is no critical angle.

Comment: The question is not about the critical angle , ok , let say the critical angle for a pair of media is 40 degrees ,what I'm trying to say is that when retracing a ray incedent at 38 (<40) degrees and that of 5 degrees give different apparent depths. (Try drawing it )

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Probably this will help your question